# No such table in ZSS Test Client window

Tags: zumero

Using the Test Client, I get a "No Such Table" error when trying to select some data from my database - sync was successful.

Here's my query: `select * from schema.TableName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
```

i.e. without the schema name in front

Or, if the table was from a schema other than `dbo`, it will be prefixed by the schema name + `_` (see [SQL Server Schemas](http://zumero.com/docs/zumero_for_sql_server_manager.html#sql-server-schemas) in the ZSS Manager docs). So if the original table was MySchema.TableName, you'd use:

```
SELECT * from MySchema_TableName
```

Comment: @PaulRoub Hmm I was under impression that this is MSSQL or alike system question, which parse schema name if provided, and use default schema if not. This way there should be no need just dropping schema part from table reference, and this won't work. (Good thing there was no downvote accompanied.)

Comment: @Vesper No, OP is having trouble selecting at the other end of the sync, from SQLite. The MSSQL schema will not have come along.